# Codeigniter Core class Can't load(Linux)

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my windows web server its all okay, even if I put it in the subfolder the core class are loaded successfully, BUT when I upload it to the Linux server in the subfolder, I get an error that there are no class MY_someclass extending CI_Controller in the core, how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Check your capitalization on your classes & files - Windows doesn't care, Linux does

99.9% of the time this is the issue